# Input checkbox not passing its Model Value to the controller if I make disabled using or condition

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

I have given the code to make make the checkbox disabled conditionally , but when I call post method , always the value being passed as null rather than its model value. How can I pass model value  to  post method after disabled

My code

```
input type="checkbox" disabled="@(isdisabled || isDofDisabled ? "disabled" : null)" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsDayOffMarked"  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> always the value being passed as null rather than its model value

For each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern `prefix.property_name`. If nothing is found, it looks for just `property_name` without the prefix. Your frontend name is like: `attendanceLogList[index].IsDayOffMarked`. So the receive data could like below:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Index(List<Attendance> attendanceLogList)
 {
    return View();
 }
```

Or using parent model:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Test Test)
{
    return View();
}
```

My testing model design:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<Attendance> attendanceLogList { get; set; }
}
public class Attendance
{
    public bool IsDayOffMarked { get; set; }
}
```

> How can I pass model value to post method after disabled

Browsers **do not support disabled property** to [submit with forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) by default.

To fix such issue,you could set **a hidden input** to store the value:

```
@model Test

<form method="post">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.attendanceLogList.Count(); i++)
    {
        if(isdisabled||isDofDisabled)
        {
            <input hidden asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsDayOffMarked" />
        }
        <input type="checkbox"
               disabled="@(isdisabled || isDofDisabled ? "disabled" : null)"
               asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsDayOffMarked" />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Post" />
</form>
```

**Note:**

Not sure what is your detailed backend code, if still receives null value, try to add `[FromForm]` before the parameter to specify the source:

```
public IActionResult Index([FromForm]List<Attendance> attendanceLogList)
```

Or:

```
public IActionResult Index([FromForm]Test Test)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need the "name" attribute for the post. I recommend rather than standard HTML tag to use:

```cs
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isDofDisabled)
```

Comment: how can I use OR statement isdisabled || isDofDisabled

Comment: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isDofDisabled, new {@checked="checked"}) You can add a new property in the model that does that and then bind the checkbox to that

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making enable those properties before submitting. I wrote a function in the Jquery.js file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).